# From a number that map to a permutation, how to generate other permutations that differ from the previous perm. by swapping of elements?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, permutation, factorial

Using [Lehmer code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code), any [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of a sequence of N elements can be encoded and mapped to a decimal number using the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Example :

Lehmer codes for `ABCD` permutations :

```
ABDC => 0010
CBAD => 2100
DCBA => 3210
```

These `inversions vectors` can be converted to a decimal using factorials :

```
2100 => 2 x 3! + 1 x 2! + 0 x 1! + 0 x 0!
     => 2 x 6  + 1 x 2  + 0 x 1  + 0 x 1
     => 14
```

So `CBAD` permutation can be map directly to number `14`.

My question is :

From a number that map to a permutation, is there a computationally efficient method to generate numbers of other permutations that differ from the previous permutation by swapping two elements in the sequence ?

---

Example :
We have 4 (which map to `ADBC`) and we want to swap the first two elements. Result is 18 (or `DABC`).

```
4    => 18
0200 => 3000
ADBC => DABC
```

Method would be declared like this :

```
swap(4, 0, 1); //return 18
```

I want to avoid doing the whole process again but reverse :

```
Number => Factorial => Rebuild original permutation and swap elements (costly) =>
  Factorial => Number
```

Note :
On wikipedia there is article about [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)
but i'm not sure it would help here.

Comment: The algorithms for transforming from between number and permutation is actually rather quick - I think there is some O(number of characters) implementation possible, so I would just generate the permutation, swap and just compute the new number. For example, for int32, the number of characters is at most 13, so if you have some slow, quadratic or even cubic implementation for encoding/decoding, it should be fast enough... the only 'price' to pay in my approach is the additional (constant) extra memory (still low enough to be worth it)

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but you might be interested in my article on "swap" algorithms for permutations in C#: http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/\

Comment: Thanks all for link and suggestions, i'm having a look at it. Eric articles on permutations looks particularly promising.

Answer (score 2):

(answer to my own question)

I finally found out. It took me a while but here is final formula :

```
int swap(int value, int indexA, int indexB)
{
   int valueA = value % factorial(indexA+1) / factorial(indexA);
   int valueB = value % factorial(indexB+1) / factorial(indexB);

   int deltaA = valueB - valueA;
   if (valueB >= valueA) deltaA++;

   int deltaB = valueA - valueB;
   if (valueA > valueB) deltaB--;

   return value + (deltaA * factorial(indexA)) + (deltaB * factorial(indexB));
}

//note: indexes have to be given from right to left
//so to swap elements at 0, 1 for 4 : swap(4, 3, 2);
```

---

Some explanation :

as an example, lets take `14`. the factorial representation is :

```
2 x 3! + 1 x 2! + 0 x 1! + 0 x 0!
```

if we want to swap the first two elements of the sequence (`CBAD` => `BCAD` or `2100` => `1100`), we need to take `2` and `1` terms in the factorial, and exchange them :

```
1 x 3! + 2 x 2! + 0 x 1! + 0 x 0!
```

note: since the factorial expression is just a sum, we do not need to reevaluate the full expression, just to apply some delta :

```
  1 x 3! + 2 x 2! + 0 x 1! + 0 x 0!

= 2 x 3! + 1 x 2! + 0 x 1! + 0 x 0! - ( 1 x 3!) + ( 1 x 2!)

= 14 - ( 1 x 3!) + ( 1 x 2!)
```

the extraction of factorial terms is done in the first two lines of code, and delta are applied at the last line.

note: we need to take care since we swapped elements, the indices inside Lehmer code might have changed, and optionally add 1 or remove 1 to terms inside factorial :

```
=> 14 - ( 1 x 3!) + ( 0 x 2!)

= 14 - 6 = 8
```

this last part is done in the two "if" conditions in c# code